# Nodejs Mongo creating collection model with a list of object where these objects are list as well

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, collections

I want to query Mongodb to get all the cars that belong to the same company **but** I don't want to search the whole db and then check each car record for its company name **rather** I want to have a list of all the cars of that same company at one place separate in my carGarage Mongo collection so I can just get the whole list at once.

This is the kind of model I want : the problem is these company names are not hard-coded, i.e. if a new entry comes into database I will have to create a new list object with that name. I think that can be done just using some if conditions in the Nodejs backend.

```
carsGarage {
    bmw: [
            car1 {
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<
            },
            car2 {
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<

            },car3 {
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<

            }
        ],

    jaguar: [
            car1 {
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<

            },
            car2 {
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<

            }
          ],
    ferrari [
            {-- -- --}
            {-- -- --}
            {-- -- --} 
        ]   
}
```

but after reading about Mongo, mainly about indexing, I think there is another way I can do this. So now I have the structure as:

```
   carsGarage {

            car1 { bmw ,
                 Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<
            },
            car2 {bmw ,
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<
            },car3 {jaguar ,
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<
            }


            car4 { bmw,
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<
            },
            car5 { jaguar,
                Model,  Year, PriceInINR,  Trim,
                Engine, Body,color ,transmittion_type;
                dealer - id_2: <<
            }


            { ferrari -- -- --}
            { ferrari -- -- --}
            { ferrari -- -- --}

    }
```

The idea is to make the company name as index : so as mongo specifies when it creates  indexes, it stores them separately so it could be searched faster, --> and it is not necessary that the indexes has to be unique it can be non-unique too

e.g. `db.collection.createIndex( { name: -1 } , {unique = true})`, but we can just drop the `{unique = true}` option `db.collection.createIndex( { name: -1 })`.

So with that when I will find all the cars of any company I will get it faster.

This is all I can think of, am I right or not, and how can I make my model better to make my search faster?

for now my model in nodejs looks like this

```
"use strict";

const MONGOOSE = require("mongoose"),
      DB = MONGOOSE.connection;


let carGarageSchema = MONGOOSE.Schema({

      company: { 
            type: String,
            required: true
      },
      model: {
            type: String,
            required: true
      },
      year: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
      },
      PriceInINR: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
      },
      trim: {
            type: String,
            required: true

      },
      engine: {
            type: String,
            required: true
      },
      body: {
            type: String,
            required: true
      },
      color: {
            type: String,
            required: true
      },
      transmission: {
            type: String,
            required: true
      },
      dealer_id: {
            type: String,
            required: true
      }
});

let collection_name = "carsGarage";

let carGarageModel = MONGOOSE.model(collection_name, carGarageSchema);
createAscendingIndex_on_car_make(DB);

module.exports = carGarageModel;




//   indexing  at schema level -->  using node js
function createAscendingIndex_on_car_company(DB, callback) {
      let collection = DB.collection(collection_name); 

      // ? Create the index
      collection.createIndex({
            company: 1, // specifies : indexing type is ascending indexing
      }, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
            }
            // callback("result");
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** 
[image]

Based on your requirements (you always want to get all the cars for a certain company) I would create a document called "company" which contains a list of the cars which belongs to that company.

```
{
  "companyName" : "Ferrari",
  "compayAddress" : "Italy",
  "companyPhoneNumber": "+1288213123",
  "cars" : [
    {
      "model": "812 superfast",
      "year" : "",
      "PriceInINR" : "",
      "trim" : "",
      "engine" : "",
      "body" : "",
      "color" : "",
      "transmission": "",
      "dealer_id" : ""
    }
    ]
}
```

In this case, the query should be pretty simple. You just query for the company name and then return the list of cars which belongs to the company.
The index will be in the companyName and it will be unique.

In case you want to insert a new car, I will first check if the company exists and if not I will create the company document and then insert the card inside that.

**Note:**
Your approach is good too, but since MongoDB is a document-oriented DB and in this case, your data has a clear hierarchy I would code it in the way I wrote.

Comment: Are you suggesting to create a new collection for each company? and when  new car come if its collection does not exists then first make a collection and then add to it.  Is this your idea,

Comment: Not a collection but a document. The collection is just one (companies) and you can create it empty initially.
When a new car is coming, if there is not a document inside the collection for the company of the car, you create it and place the car inside.
But no need to create more than one collection. I hope it is clear :)

Comment: ok I got it, so I think I should make the company name as index -> with option unique as set? what do u think, will it improve the speed?

Comment: Yes, I think that is the right way to go. You can easily set a unique index in the companyName. About the performance speed:
To be honest, there are not that many cars for each car company so I don't think you will see differences in performance, you will query at most 1000 objects (?).


But grouping all the cars inside a document bring other advantages that it may be useful or not depending on your application requirements and I think it is the right data model.

Comment: yeah you are right, in my companies collection there will be only like at most 50 companies so it would be useless and waste of memory to make indexes for 50 elements. **thanks**